# Arcade Intersects returns geometries with same areas

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

I am writing an Arcade expression for a pop-up that will intersect the selected geometry with an underlying layer that has 6 different types of values (C, S, R, O, OC, EMO). I want the expression to return which of the 6 values are present within the selected geometry, and their acreage. The expression does seem to return the correct list of values (selecting various geometries returns different combinations), however the area calculations seem to reflect the total acreage of the underlying layer for the category.

```
var intersectLayer = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map, "Sewersheds_Dissolve"),$feature)
var types = ""
for (var f in intersectLayer){

types = concatenate(types," ",f.TYPE," - ", Text(Round(Area(f,'Acres'),2),'#,###'),TextFormatting.NewLine)
}
return types
```

For example, selecting Geometry A returns:

[image]

and selecting Geometry B returns

[image]

Different underlying intersection lists, but the same areas values. As if the geometries for the intersected layer is not updated after the intersect. Also the areas way too large since they reflect the entire underlying 'Sewershed_Dissolve' layer.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help file for Intersects() it says:

> Indicates if one geometry intersects another geometry.

So its testing the spatial relationship for geometries that are intersecting, it is not computing the intersection of geometries.

You need only to scroll up to the next function in the help file to [Intersection()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#intersection) and they even give a sample of code to return the area.